# Not able to handle Authorization using JWT

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Im trying to create a protected route , once the user logs in user is issued a token and this token is checked when user tries to access a protected resource . Im able to generate the token and send it back as a response as the below code,

```
const token = jwt.sign({_id:found._id.toString()},process.env.KEY);
res.header('token', token );
res.render("dashboard");
```

So after a user is logged in , i go to the dashboard and i can see the response header where token is set as token .But when i try to navigate to the secret resource page the auth handler gets a request,but the request does not have a token in the header so im not able to verify it.

```
router.get('/secret',auth,function(req,res)
{
   res.render('secret')
}
);
```

Trying to figure out how to set the token header correctly so it is issued and can verify it.

Answer (score 0):

on client side, you should send token in header as authorization

after that, you can receive client's token on backend side using 
req.get('Authorization')
and verify it using 
jwt.verify